# example code for filepicker.io rails drag and drop?

Tags: filepicker.io

I'm using the filepicker rails gem here:

https://github.com/Filepicker/filepicker-rails

I'd like to convert an existing rails upload form to use the filepicker.io rails gem. The existing form uses rails, bootstrap, and datamapper and looks like this:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @photo],
  html: {multipart: true, remote: true, class: 'photo-upload'} ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user.id %>
  <div class="select-files">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :image, "Select files from your computer" %>
      <%= f.file_field :image, multiple: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Upload", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My conversion looks like this:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @photo]) do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :image, "Select files from your computer:" %>
    <%= f.filepicker_field :image %> 
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I followed the documentation on the github project, but I don't get a file picker dialog. Is there a demo or example code that uses filepicker.io rails to demonstrate a working upload form? I found this:

https://github.com/maxtilford/filepicker-rails-demo

but I can't get it working on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the newer github repo at https://github.com/Filepicker/filepicker-rails